# OpenVPN install on BusyBox embedded system

Tags: embedded, openvpn, busybox

First of all thank you for your help. I'm trying to install openVPN on a embedded device running linux together with Busybox. But right now I have a problem to installing it. Busybox is not accepting any sudo apt-get installations and I tried to install openvpn manually from the website and placed it in the right map.. after executing the installer it gaves me a lot of errors and it seems like it is not supported voor busybox ... Can someone help me out or have a solution?

I installed openvpn from this site: https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/
Moved the tar.gz map into the embedded system and runned: ./configure, this is what the results are:

```
# ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking whether make supports nested variables... no
checking build system type... armv5tejl-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
checking host system type... armv5tejl-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
checking whether make supports the include directive... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/etc/openvpn':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

Regards,

M S

Comment: Please show what you've already done instead of telling us.

Comment: So what are the contents of `config.log`? Also what `apt-get` or `apt` commands have you tried?

Comment: Does your "embedded system" have the tools that you're trying to use? Toolchain in case of compilation, apt in case of trying to install deb packets. Docs for embedded system should normally tell you how to install additional software. In worst case you might need to crosscompile on another machine and copy the resulting binaries.

Answer (score 0):

```
# vi config.log
configure:3361: result: awk
configure:3372: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:3398: result: no
configure:3423: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:3440: result: no
configure:3569: checking build system type
configure:3583: result: armv5tejl-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
configure:3603: checking host system type
configure:3616: result: armv5tejl-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
configure:3640: checking whether make supports the include directive
configure:3655: make -f confmf.GNU && cat confinc.out
configure: ./configure.lineno: line 3674: make: not found
configure:3658: $? = 127
configure:3655: make -f confmf.BSD && cat confinc.out
configure: ./configure.lineno: line 3674: make: not found
configure:3658: $? = 127
configure:3677: result: no
configure:3747: checking for gcc
configure:3777: result: no
configure:3840: checking for cc
configure:3887: result: no
configure:3943: checking for cl.exe
configure:3973: result: no
configure:3997: error: in `/etc/openvpn':
configure:4000: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

Comment: This is what I get in the config.log file.